# Передача событий в WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Здравствуйте.

Интересуе, возможно ли, чтобы клиент передал в качестве данных хосту событие?

У меня клиент просто подписывается на данные таблицы, но лишь на некоторые, которые как раз хорошо отсеиваются фильтрами типа `(row ) => (row.Field_A == 'Val1' || row.Field_B == 'Val2')`. Пробовал возвращать это событие в составе DataContract класса, но ничего не получилось, WCF вроде его даже не сериализует. Это как-то возможно сделать?

Спасибо.

Comment: Нет, событие — это не данные. Вам придётся сделать метод Subscribe, после которого клиенту будет приходить вызов callback'а. (Возможно, для этого понадобится дуплексное соединение.)

Comment: Т.е. передавать строку таблицы обратно клиенту, чтобы он сам прогонял это событие, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @nvse: У вас событие — это `event`? Если да, то вам виднее, что нужно обработчику на той стороне.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо. Правда, данные у меня приходят с очень большой частотой, и дергать постоянно клиента (1 раз полезный на 10 ненужных) мне не хочется. Поэтому, наверное, тогда лучше передать эти фильтры в виде объектов сразу серверу. Но это, конечно, будет не так удобно, как через события, ну ладно.

Comment: Посмотрите, может, здесь http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/596287/Broadcasting-Events-with-a-Duplex-WCF-Service что полезное для Вас.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понял, клиенту надо получить необходимые данные, как только они поступят на сервер, не перегружая себя при этом запросами? Но ведь существуют не только асинхронные запросы от клиента, но и асинхронные ответы сервера, то есть сервер ответит на запрос только при поступлении нужных данных в базу! Может, это поможет?